# I'm trying to make a simple program in python, but im stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a very simple program in `python`, but it says syntax invalid in an error window. I cant understand what's wrong with it:

```
print('What is your name?')
YourName = input()
if YourName == "Alice":
    print('Hello Alice')
elif print('How old are you?')
    age = input()
elif age < 4:
        print('And you know how to write at young age!')
```

Comment: You need to convert `age` to an `int`, so `age = int(input())`.

Comment: You're missing a colon and proper indentation

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print('What is your name?')
YourName = input()
if YourName == "Alice":
    print('Hello Alice')
else:
    print('How old are you?')
    age = int(input())
    if age < 4:
        print('And you know how to write at young age!')
```

And a one-liner:

```
print("Hello Alice") if input("What is your name ")=="Alice" else print('And you know how to write at young age!') if int(input("How old are you? "))<4 else None
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem with your Code

Welcome! The following line is wrong:

```
elif print('How old are you?')
```

There are two main reasons behind this:

1. `print('How old are you?')` is not a normal condition. Although this is technically fine since your compiler will evaluate it as type `None` and treat it as if it is `False`, you might want to replace that part with something that is conceptually meaningful.
2. You're missing a colon after the `elif`. For example:

   ```
   elif (int(input()) < 4):
       #your code
   ```

### Solution

```
print('What is your name?')
YourName = input()
if YourName == "Alice":
    print('Hello Alice')
else:
    print('You are not Alice! How old are you?')
    if int(input()) < 4:
        print('You know how to write at young age!')
```

Comment: None evaluates to False. The other issue there is the lack of colon anywhere.

Comment: You're right - I will edit accordingly if you are ok with it. However, the user mentioned they were beginners in python so I think that info will be of use to them. Also the cast `int(input())` is missing.

Comment: Comments in Python start with #, not //

Comment: Should be `int(input())`